# How to display values in asp:textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Wanted to display data in `asp:textbox` using JavaScript. When I am using HTML textbox the value is displayed on the text box. But data is not displayed when using `asp:Textbox`.

```
function SearchDealer()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: "DealerDetails.aspx/GetDealerDetails",
        data: "{DlrId:'" + dealerID + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data)
        {  
            //This is a html text box so value is dsplayed.
            document.getElementById('txt_sapcode').value = data.d.sapcode;

            //No values displayed in this asp:textBox
            document.getElementById('tex_dealername').value = data.d.DealerName;
            document.getElementById('txt_addr1').value = data.d.Add1;
        },
        error: function ()
        {
            alert("Failed to update details.");
        }
    });
    srchflg = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have some ways for your case:

1.Using ClientID:

`document.getElementById('<%=tex_dealername.ClientID%>')`

2.Add a CssClass to your TextBox control:

`<asp:Textbox ID="myTextBox" runat="server" Text="Hello, World" CssClass="TestClass" />`

then use class selector.

3.Just change ClientIDMode in web.config:

`<pages clientIDMode="Static" />` inside `<system.web></system.web>`

Answer (score 2):

`asp:Textbox` controls generate unique IDs, so this:

```
<asp:Textbox ID="myTextBox" runat="server" Text="Hello, World" />
```

Could generate something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="MyControl_myTextBox" value="Hello, World" />
```

In order to get the ID produced by ASP.NET, you can use the [ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property inside your javascript:

```
document.getElementById('<%=myTextBox.ClientID%>').value;
```

So from your example:

```
document.getElementById('<%=tex_dealername.ClientID%>').value;
```

If your `SearchDealer` function is in an external javascript file, you will not have access to the ClientID property, so you will need to pass it from your ASP.NET page:

```
<!-- This file contains your SearchDealer function -->
<script src="externalFile.js"></script>
<!-- Call SearchDealer with a parameter from your .NET page -->
<script>
    SearchDealer(document.getElementById('<%=tex_dealername.ClientID%>').value);
</script>
```

Your function definition would then need to be declared as:

```
function SearchDealer(dealerName) {
    // Do something with dealerName
}
```

Comment: Small note : This will not work for Javascript that is not included inside the `.ASPX` page at compile time. (i.e. In an External JS File)

Answer (score 1):

Using ASP.NET controls, gives you a unique ID generated on the serverside ,  your id look like this  `ctl00_contentPlaceHolder_tex_dealername`

Client side code :

```
$("input[id$='tex_dealername']").val(data.d.DealerName);  //option 1
$('<%= tex_dealername.ClientID %>').val(data.d.DealerName); //option 2
```

or if you assigned any unique class so call by class name

```
$('.yourClassName').val(data.d.DealerName);
```

Comment: @RGraham: downvote accepted, but as OP used `$.ajax` this clearly indicate jquery lib are there so whats harm in writing with jquery syntax

Answer (score 1):

For Html control use :
 $("#TextboxId").val("Value");

For Asp.net textbox control use :
 $("[id$=TextboxId]").val("Value");

Answer (score 0):

Add a CssClass property to asp:Textbox and get it using jquery ($(".class"))